# How can I change favicons depending on Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

As I said in the title, I am trying to use JavaScript to update the favicon (shortcut icon) depending on Bootstrap Carousels.
For example, As the carousel changes to the second slide, 2.ico should be the favicon, as the carousel changes to the third slide, 3.ico should be the favicon. Here's what I have done.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="1.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>


<!-- bootstrap boilerplate html for carousels -->
<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="bootstrap.js">
<script>
  if (   /*slide 2 is active*/   ) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].setAttribute("href", "2.ico");
  }
if (   /*slide 3 is active*/   ) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].setAttribute("href", "3.ico");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Go check the Bootstrap documentation, it explains which events you can subscribe to to trigger your own functionality, when the active carousel item changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to your carousel. You have more detail explanation in the [docs page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#events). But a simple javascript example for your HTML would be

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   const myCarousel = document.getElementById('carouselExampleControls')

   myCarousel.addEventListener('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
      let currentIndex = $('.carousel-item.active').index() + 1;
      // do something...
   })
});
</script>
```